# Сканер в java работает не так как нужно, что не так?

Tags: java

```
package WorkSpace;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class WorkSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       ArrayList<String> box1 = new ArrayList<>();
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  


       //заполнение списка
       System.out.print("Введите кол-во операций: ");
       int numberOfOperations = scan.nextInt();
       for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfOperations;i++){
           System.out.print("Введите значние " + i + " : ");
           String x = scan.nextLine();           
           box1.add(x);
       }

       //вывод списка
       for(String j: box1){
           System.out.print(j+" ");
       }

    }
}



ввыводит что-то типа этого
```

Введите кол-во операций: 4

Введите значние 1 : Введите значние 2 : 5

Введите значние 3 : 6

Введите значние 4 : 6

я не понимаю почему он пропускает 1-ый сканер???

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberOfOperations = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();     
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfOperations; i++) {
  ...
```

---

> а почему так происходит?

Потому что `scan.nextInt` не считывает конец строки, который считывaется следующим `scan.nextLine`.

Comment: С помощью `scan.skip("\\s+")` можно.

Comment: а почему так происходит?

Comment: @Den4_x Потому что `scan.nextInt` не считывает конец строки, который считывется следующим `scan.nextLine`.